# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on every main() function I create

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

This problem only started recently, but all my main functions on various programs don't work (they have worked in the past).

They now all return:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.Prefix.main(Prefix.java:40)
```

Here is an example of a class that gives this error:

```
package PACKAGE_NAME_HERE;

public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error message is pointing to a different class, line 40. Obviously this has nothing to do with the class you posted. Are you sure you're trying to execute the correct project?

Comment: Agreed, there's probably some reference to args[0] in one of your main methods, that is unchecked by a call to the length of the arguments provided.  In other words, you're most likely calling some class' main without arguments, and referencing the args array unsafely.

Comment: I am sure that I am running the right file. And nothing in that main method is referencing args

Answer (score 0):

You're calling method main in com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.Prefix (which is part of Maven, source can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.0/com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/lib/sql/Prefix.java)) from somewhere.

Line 40: `String m = e(args[0]);`

And if you don't pass any command-line arguments, you don't have args[0], and you got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

That's all I can tell from your question(can't use comments yet, but more clarification/what did you change recently(anything about Maven?) would be nice).

Comment: I don't think I changed any of the Maven stuff, at least not on purpose.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the project and making a new one fixed this error. Not sure why, maybe I accidentally messed up the setup or something.